# Resizing EFI partition followed by MSR (Microsoft Reserved Partition) - Arch Linux

Tags: linux, partitioning, uefi, efi, boot-partition

I have a dual boot setup (Arch/Windows 10) and after installing Windows 10 BIOS update, my ESP partition is now full. I did not follow the Arch recommendations to set the ESP partition to 550MB and I am now paying the price.

I would love to safely increase it to 500MB, however, it is followed by a MSR, which most people advise never touching.

[image]

Ideally, I would like to reduce the size of the partition 3, which is my Windows partition. Anyone knows how I can safely perform such an operation or if it's even worth trying?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: a good soul for help?

Comment: or at least offering an alternative?

Comment: "after installing Windows 10 BIOS update" What that has to do with anything??? Please tell me you are not using grub. Both linux kernel and windows can boot from its own bootloaders, EFISTUB for linux kernel. Moreover, windows kernel can boot from C:\Windows\Boot\EFI Your partition ESP is too large it should be only 100 MiB, but really for windows only 30 MiB are used.